# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - don't understand why?

Tags: java

I'm still a beginner with Java and writing a student record programme at the moment, and im stuck with these errors, and can't work out why.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Results.Results(Results.java:11)
at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

This is where the error is in my main class, on line 21 (second line below).

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        StudentNames nameInputobject = new StudentNames();
        nameInputobject.StudentNames();


        Subject subjectInputobject = new Subject();
        subjectInputobject.Subject();

        StudentNumber numberInputobject = new StudentNumber();
        numberInputobject.StudentNumber();      

        StudentYear yearInputobject = new StudentYear();
        yearInputobject.StudentYear();  

        Results resultsInputobject = new Results();
        resultsInputobject.Results();   // <<<error here




    }
}
```

and the error in my results class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Results 
{
    public static void Results()
    {

        StudentYear obj=new StudentYear();
        ArrayList<Integer> studentYear=obj.getStudentYear();
        int year=studentYear.get(0); // <<<<error here 
        ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter the results for "+year+":");
        results.add(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println(results);

        }
    }
```

the results class gets the studentYear value from an arraylist in another class 
code here.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentYear 
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> studentYear;
    public void StudentYear()
    {
        studentYear = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter the year the student has most recently completed: ");
        studentYear.add(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println(studentYear);
        }
        public ArrayList<Integer> getStudentYear()
        {
            return studentYear;
            }
}
```

And i'm using Arraylists as i plan on making the programme loop in the end to hold multiple student values

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `studentYear` variable is an instance of `ArrayList<Integer>`. This means it's a collection of the object `Integer`. This is a "boxed" wrapper around the primitive data type `int`.

An `Integer` object can be null, however an `int` cannot.

Given you have not added anything to this ArrayList, the the element at position zero will be null. When the VM attempts to convert this `null` instance of `Integer` to the primtive `int` it is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: the main code shows that yearinput happens before going into resultsinput, and in the year inpuit i specify a value to go into the arraylist studentYear, that later (in the results class) will give year its value.
Thats what i understand.

Comment: That is a different instance of `StudentYear`. See in your Results class where you create a brand new instance `StudentYear obj=new StudentYear();`. After that you never add anything to the list. If you want to reference the `StudentYear` created in the `Main` class, then you should pass it to `Result.results()` as a parameter

Comment: Ah i see, I don't want to add anything to the list, i would like to access the value in the list that i specified in the previous class (studentYear), so i can ask the user in the next class(results) to enter the result for that year. Thank you for your help by the way, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @user3050340 So delete line 9 of Results.java and change the method to `public static void Results(StudentYear studentYear)` and pass in the year you created in the `Main` class.

Comment: I've deleted line 9 in Results.java and have changed the method, I dont quite understand what you mean about passing the year though.

I'm currently getting an error still here   `int year=studentYear.get(0);` on results.java class